# What's the meaning of "would have been"?

Tags: would-have-been

"Who would've thought that working with you would have been a silver lining?" Actually, I don't quite understand the usage of "would have been"? What's the difference if I replace "would have been" with "was"?

Comment: Could you give us the source of the quote?  I personally would prefer either "Who would've thought that working with you would have a silver lining?"

Comment: Over 5000 questions tagged "would have been".

Comment: @aparente001 I think your suggestion changes the intended meaning. The wording in the question means (to me) that some situation was generally bad but working with you was a good aspect of it. Your wording means (to me) that working with you was generally bad but some aspect of it was good.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - I see what you mean.  In that case, I guess I would propose "Who would've thought that working here would have a silver lining -- getting to work with you!"

Comment: @aparente001 To me, as to a non-native speaker, using "would have been" seems to infer that their joint working had ceased by the moment of saying that soppy words. Isn't it?

Comment: @Eugene - Are you talking about the phrasing in the original question, or my proposal?

Comment: @aparente001  I'm talking about the phrasing in the original question. Judging by your proposal I should have thought that workng is still taking place.

Comment: @Eugene - I guess I agree....  I think someone might use my proposal on their last day as they're cleaning out their desk or saying good-bye.  / You can adjust my proposal for a variety of situations -- that's the fun of tenses!

Comment: @aparente001 It's true (the fun of tenses) insomuch as English is an analytic language. I've been long grubbing around for the slightest possibility of using "would+Perfect Infinitive" for future references. But so far I have found no comprehension of it by the native speakers.

Comment: I just used the following analysis: "I will have finished my masterpiece by the 1-st of February 2022 if your brother is so kind to give me back my frabjous chisel" - (then I transform this pattern into that of unreal condition) "I would have finished my masterpiece by the 1-st of February 2022 if your brother were so kind to give me back my frabjous chisel". What would your perspective on such a development be and how about its perspectives to take on?

Comment: @Eugene - Any reason you aren't writing a Question about this? / Wodehouse wrote an introduction to one of his books that went approximately like this: "This book is dedicated to my stepdaughter Lenora, without whose help it would have been finished in half the time." / You could say, "I would have finished my masterpiece by the 1-st of February 2022 if your brother had been so kind as to return the loan of my laptop."

Comment: @aparente001 Thanks a lot! You are the first who got to understanding my implication as far as Future Perfect used in conditional sentences (of unreal condition) is concerned. I've asked questions on this issue on Stackexchange a couple of times. But I didn't accrue any eligible answer precisely because native speakers couldn't add up how "woukd+Perfect Inf." might relay the idea of the unreal future consequence, as it is.

Comment: And, by the way, why did you use Past Perfect in the subordinate clause? Is it possible to employ modal "would" (volition),i.e. "...if your brother would be so kind as to return the loan of my laptop (he hasn't returned it yet, maybe he will do it in a week but he also may not do this at all)."?

Comment: @Eugene - Glad I could help.  Let's do this in a Q&A format.  Please post a link here once you've posted your question -- thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132849/discussion-between-eugene-and-aparente001).

Answer (score 1):

Using "Would have been":
Here, the implication is such that before you had worked with him, you never felt that working with him would be a silver lining. Maybe you had some qualms.
But, after working with him, you are actually registering your surprise by saying this line.

Answer (score 1):

The implication that user3847720’s answer mentions is already made with the beginning of the sentence, "Who would've thought." The second instance of "would have" does nothing to emphasize this.

Using *was* instead of *would have been* feels awkward here because you're moving into past tense. But the original version feels awkward because they've used a contraction of *would* and *have* at the start of the sentence, and then used those same two words later on in the same sentence, so neither is a good option.

"Who would've thought there would be a silver lining to working with you."

This seems the best choice to me. Essentially the use of *would have been* here is redundant, and replacing it with *was* doesn't work.